# Query objects inside a record and pass to router.get to display on table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I have a collection that has three fields: name(String), email(String) and appointments(Object)

I query the collection inside a router.get based on user email

```
router.get('/appointments', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
var query = {email: req.user.email};
PatientList.find(query, function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('appointments', {data : data, title: 'Appointments'});
});
});
```

data from the query above looks like this:

```
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'dan',
  email: 'dan@gmail.com',
  appointments: 
[ { _id: 58373466542d6ae430a13337,
    position: '1',
    name: 'dan',
    email: 'dan@gmail.com',
    serviced: false,
    hospital: 'Toronto hospital',
    date: 'Thursday, November 24, 2016',
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5837346a542d6ae430a13339,
    position: '2',
    name: 'dan',
    email: 'dan@dan.com',
    serviced: false,
    hospital: 'Calgary hospital',
    date: 'Thursday, November 24, 2016',
    __v: 0 },
]
```

I want to access these fields inside the appointments field and display them on a table using handlebars. My html with handlebars looks like this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Clinic</td>
        <td>Appointment Date</td>
        <td>Patient Number</td>
        <td>Clinic Queue Status</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each data}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{this.appointments.hospital}}</td>
            <td>{{this.appointments.date}}</td>
            <td>{{this.appointments.position}}</td>
            <td>{{#if this.appointments.serviced}}
                    Please return to the clinic immediately.
                  {{else}}
                      Patient is currently being served.
                {{/if}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it is not printing anything in the table

Answer (score 0):

Passing properties to your view ( template ) via `res.render` results in those properties become available for use in your template.

You are passing a `data` property in your handlebars template, so you need to use your `data` variable inside, which is an object, that contains the `appointments` array.

In order to properly render them you need to use `#each` against `data.appointments` like :

```
{{#each data.appointments}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{hospital}}</td>
        <td>{{date}}</td>
        <td>{{position}}</td>
        <td>{{#if serviced}}
                Please return to the clinic immediately.
              {{else}}
                  Patient is currently being served.
            {{/if}}
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Also keep in mind that when you use `#each` all of the properties of your array are served as locals for this block. So `this.` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: its not working, its still not showing anything. One thing I should mention is that the I add those objects in the appointments field by querying another collection and saving inside that field:

QueuedUser.find({email: req.user.email}, function(err, list){
                                if (err) throw err;
                                PatientList({name: req.user.name, email: req.user.email,  appointments: list}).save(function(err,data) {
if (err) throw err; 
res.redirect('/users/appointments');
                                });